# Compile Time Exception due to different datatypes

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting following error while compiling:

- 'UnitType/*1*/' is from 'package:yummy/utils/Constants.dart' ('lib/utils/Constants.dart').
  package:yummy/utils/constants.dart:1
- 'UnitType/*2*/' is from 'package:yummy/utils/constants.dart' ('lib/utils/constants.dart').
  package:yummy/utils/constants.dart:1
  unitType: UnitType.volume,

I have two files involved: unit_specs.dart and constants.dart

UnitSpecs Model:

```
import '../utils/constants.dart';

class UnitSpecs {
   final String shortcut;

   final UnitType unitType;

   const UnitSpecs({
       required this.shortcut,
       required this.unitType,
   });
}
```

constants.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as mat;
import '../models/unit_specs.dart';

enum UnitType {
   weight,
   volume,
   amount,
}

enum Unit {
   quantity,
   gram,
   kilogram,
   milliliter,
   liter,
}

const unitSpecsMap = {
   Unit.quantity: UnitSpecs(
     shortcut: 'x',
     unitType: UnitType.amount,
   ),
   Unit.gram: UnitSpecs(
     shortcut: 'g',
     unitType: UnitType.weight,
   ),
   Unit.kilogram: UnitSpecs(
     shortcut: 'kg',
     unitType: UnitType.weight,
   ),
   Unit.milliliter: UnitSpecs(
     shortcut: 'ml',
     unitType: UnitType.volume,
   ),
   Unit.liter: UnitSpecs(
     shortcut: 'l',
     unitType: UnitType.volume,
   ),
};

class Constants{
 static const mat.TextStyle ...
}
```

I have no clue why the compiler thinks there are two different UnitType datatypes?

Thanks for help

I tried to refactor the UnitType enum, giving different namespaces to the imports and I checked every other file in the project of other UnitType datatypes. Nothing found!

Comment: The file is lower cased `constants.dart`? It seems it is loaded once as CamelCase, and another in lowercase.

Comment: yes the file is named constants.dart . There is no other file called Constants.dart in this project

Comment: The error indicates that somewhere you are importing the `constants.dart` file with inconsistent capitalization.  The Dart compiler will treat `import 'constants.dart';` and `import 'Constants.dart';` as two separate Dart libraries even if your filesystem is case-insensitive and resolves those filenames to the same file on disk.  *Be consistent.*